# error c2661 in using discrete distribution in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, probability-density

Below code implements a discrete probability distribution function over 0,1,..,n^2-1 (that I defined its value earlier in my program). At the end I got an instance of this pdf which is "number" value.

But for some reasons that I don't know, I'v got two errors, one:
**"expected constant size"** for **"int prob[val]"**  another error is: **"error c2661"**  for **discrete distribution** that tells me it may not get two arguments but I need to give two parameter to it and I have seen examples of it before...

Thanks in advance

```
    vector< double> weights( n);
    for( int count = 0; count < (n*n); ++count) {
        weights[count] = pdf( i,count,n);
    }
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::discrete_distribution<int> distribution( weights.begin(), weights.end()) ;

    int number=0;
    const int val = n*n;
    int prob[val]={};

    for ( int count=0; count<(n*n); ++count ) {
        number = distribution( generator);
        ++prob[number];
    }
```

Comment: Arrays in c++ cannot be variably defined (though gcc provides it as a non-standard extension).  Use a vector instead.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, I will fix that. do you have any comment about the other error?

Comment: @omid: Make sure you show a complete example that can reproduce the error, otherwise we are left to make guesses. My guess is you didn't include `<random>`.

Comment: I don't believe Microsoft's discrete_distribution implementation provides a range constructor.  What version of VC++ is this?  (also: see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab05fd86-7e78-4419-aea2-90ba533b0fa3/initializing-a-stddiscretedistribution )

Comment: @joe: Your right, [there is a bug filed for the missing ctor](http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812538/stl-std-discrete-distribution-missing-constructor-from-iterator-pair).

Comment: @JesseGood No I included the random header, otherwise I guess I would have got different error.